# Solana SPL Token logo doesn't show anywhere

Tags: spl-token, phantom-wallet, solscan, fungible-token, metaboss

I made an token using spl-token before I found out about the new standards. So I uploaded my metadata using Metaboss and my token name and symbol appear in Solscan and Phantom wallet but my logo doesn't appear anywhere. My image is a png, 300x300px, and is under 200kb. My image is hosted on Github and my metadata file is pinned on Pinata. I've searched Google and forums for days and couldn't find an answer. Can someone please help me fix this?
Here's the code from the json file I uploaded with Metaboss:

```
{
  "name": "Solspark",
  "symbol": "SPRK",
  "uri": "https://chocolate-elaborate-wasp-878.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmXQZHN3LNfUUnvSE2TWB7jcE7VEdNos8JAH8BuB7uaCNa",
  "seller_fee_basis_points": 0,
  "creators": null
}
```

Here's the code from my metadata json file:

```
{
  "name": "SolSpark",
  "symbol": "SPRK",
  "description": "Fully reserved fiat-backed stablecoin by Helix Labs, LLC",
  "image": "https://github.com/Amishelite/SolSpark/blob/main/logo2.png"
}
```

Comment: Same issue, created liquidity pool, metadata looks correct, but not showing logo and name not showing up on Raydium, can't search by name, only mint address, name on Jupiter but logo not on either.